# What is the purpose of the Red Hour in The Return of the Archons?

Tags: star-trek

In Season 1, Episode 21 of Star Trek (The Original Series), the landing party observes an apparently peaceful society become suddenly berserk and chaotic at 6pm. As the story develops, it becomes less and less clear why *Landru*, the reigning power, would allow this *Festival/Red Hour* to happen. In fact, much of Landru's purpose seems to be expressly to prevent this sort of behavior. In Landru's own words:

> Landru seeks tranquillity. Peace for all. The universal good.

So then, how does this violent festival serve Landru's supposed mandate of *Peace for all*?

Comment: Perhaps it's the one time of the day when everything is allowed (sort of like a release valve). Emotions were not removed in the inhabitants after all

Comment: For future reference, please specify the exact series name and season and episode number when asking a question that refers to a specific episode.  *Star Trek* has five different television series (not counting TAS), all of which have more than one season, with most seasons having 26 episodes.  While the episode name in your question title was very helpful in narrowing down the specific story in question, "Episode 21 of Star Trek" is otherwise very ambiguous.  I've edited the question body for clarity.

Comment: Do fans really remember episodes by number? I know the titles, not the episode numbers.

Comment: And where did they get the rocks?

Comment: @KeithThompson - No, but having having season/episode number makes it extremely easy to track down and watch. I can’t tell you how many times I have watched an episode after reading something on here. Having additional info is very helpful.

Comment: @iMerchant: Series and title should be just as easy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Memory Alpha's article on [Festival](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Festival) makes reference to the Red Hour being a form of population control, citing the text below from the [James Blish novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/76754.Star_Trek_9) of the episode.

> “One question, Mr. Lindstrom: Landru wanted to give his people peace
>   and security and so programmed the machine. Then how do we account for
>   so total an anomaly as the festival?”
>
> “Sir, with the machine destroyed, we’ll never have enough data to
>   answer that one with any confidence— but I have a guess, and I feel
>   almost certain it’s the right one. Landru wanted to eliminate war,
>   crime, disease, even personal dissension, and he succeeded. But he
>   failed to allow for population control, and without that even an
>   otherwise static society would soon suffer a declining standard of
>   living, and eventual outright hunger. Clearly Landru wouldn’t have
>   wanted that either, but he made no allowances for it.
>
> “So the machine devised its own: one night a year in which all forms
>   of control were shut off, every moral law abrogated; even ordinary
>   human decency was canceled out. One night of the worst kind of civil
>   war, in which every person is the enemy of every other. I have no
>   proof of this at all, sir—but it’s just the sort of solution you’d
>   expect from a machine, and furthermore, a machine that had been
>   programmed to think of people as cells in a Body, of no importance at
>   all as individuals.” Suddenly Lindstrom’s voice shook. “One night a
>   year of total cancer … horrible! I hope I’m dead wrong, but there are
>   precedents.”
>
> “That can hardly be fairly characterized as a guess,” Spock said.
>   “Ordinarily I do not expect close reasoning from sociologists, but
>   from what I know of the way computers behave when they are given
>   directives supported by insufficient data, I can find no flaw in Mr.
>   Lindstrom’s analysis. It should not distress him, for if it is
>   valid—as I am convinced it is—he is indeed just the man to put it
>   right.”

So, the Festival is not a part of the peacekeeping process at all.  It is a matter of population control.  However, it could also be theorized (and, I believe, may even have been brought up in an episode or two of some Star Trek series) that an event such as the Festival could be *necessary* to maintain an otherwise peaceful and conflict-free society such as the one on Beta III.  Without an opportunity to release its darker side now and then, such society could suffer negative effects.

Comment: That makes sense given the whole "of the Body" speech that goes on in the episode.  To extend the comparison further, it's not said how often Festival happens - it may be irregular, like getting sick, recovering, and having a stronger immune system because of it.

Comment: I don't really buy the population control theory. Landru certainly could've controlled sexual encounters between members of The Body without violence and thus had a much more direct and peaceful means of population control. The *release the dark side* theory resonates more logically with me, but is also a much less obvious need than that of population control.

Comment: @kojiro Buy it or not, that's the only (semi-) canonical answer you're likely to get.  I hate when that happens, too.

Comment: @Iszi - I've taken the liberty of replacing the Memory alpha cite with the actual quote from the book

Comment: I've corrected the markup so the last paragraph doesn't look like it's part of the quotation. Please check that I've gotten it right.

Answer (score 3):

There is a possible alternative explanation, to expand on @ChetterHummin's comment, but it assumes that the physiology of the people on that planet was similar to humans:  Hormones.

Early in the episode, just after the Red Hour starts, the Enterprise crew find Reger's place and rent a room for the night.  During that exchange, the people in there say something along the lines of "You're young, you should be participating in the Red Hour."

If they're like humans (as an unnerving number of TOS aliens were), then this age group would include rebellious teenagers that need a release valve and those in their 20s-30s who aren't ready to settle down yet.  After that point, they would reach some sort of contentment with their life and no longer participate.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumspringa

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the theories regarding population, I'd like to add that Landru takes the opportunity to go into maintenance mode, whereby he temporarily releases control of the people and recharges his energy piles and performs other internal programming housekeeping. This could explain why Kirk and party were taken to absorption chambers instead of being absorbed with the tubes. After the maintenance mode was complete (Festival over), not all systems were up 100%. Critical systems like tubes being useful for killing were available, but tubes being useful for absorbing were not, and so the tubes could be used to coerce Kirk and Spock to the absorption chamber, which was used only during these moments before Landru was back up 100%.

Comment: This seems very speculative but is at least based on what we see in the episode. You have my +1

Answer (score 1):

I have to confess I'm surprised that none of the answers here addresses a rather obvious point.  If you watch the Red Hour sequence, a large part of the mayhem is sexual.  A frenzied woman jumps onto Kirk.  Men rush off with women over their shoulders.  Others are clearly clutching at and pulling women violently to themselves.  And though some of the sheer joy of wanton madness can be seen in the eyes certain women, look at Tula's unrestrained crying fit when she returns to her father's house.  She has certainly been raped.  In a society essentially devoid of passion, when and how do the inhabitants procreate?  We are told in the final confrontation between Kirk and Landru that "the Body is dying."  This is literally true.  (We might speculate that since the inhabitants of this town speak English, they are in fact the descendants of the crew the starship Archon, and that they have been pulled down to the the surface of this world because the population of the planet is dwindling.)  Of course, a show in 1966 couldn't state it overtly, but Festival assures the conception of each new generation.  ("Now, if that's a fact, tell me--am I lying?")

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Do you have proof for your theory?

Comment: I don't think we can infer anything from the fact that they speak English. Apparently everybody in the galaxy speaks English.

Answer (score 0):

The red hour could represent a type of natural selection method that would otherwise be missing in a "perfect" society. Further evidence of this is apparent in the elder man's anger that the landing crew was not participating in the activity. By allowing the people to run rampant on their own accord, Landru could efficiently keep a check on the population and build strong loyalty by showing the potential chaos without order.

Answer (score 0):

I generally concluded that "Festival" served as an annual venting of the placid people's primal emotions, but that is only a guess. It always seemed to me that the script may have been begun with the sensational Festival vignette alone, with the plot of the final version crafted to fit around it.

The lack of explicit explanation for the "Festival" is a glaring deficiency of the episode. It is imperative in the mission of narrative to explain dramatic events without obvious cause, and this simply did not occur. The only comment made is that it is "the will of Landru," but that just does not go far enough.

I wonder if there had been an explanation, but network censors deleted it, due to its salacious nature. Whatever the cause, the audience was left stuck, and we still are, after nearly half a century.

Answer (score 0):

With so much of Landru's exposition worded in terms of "the body", and the Enterprise landing party being an "infection", I always assumed Festival to be a sort of "fever". Although it appeared to happen on a schedule, one might assume this to be due to the rigid pattern of a computer.

Answer (score 0):

As someone said above, I always thought it was Landrus way to get the people to procreate. You all look for some deep meaning to it all. It's basic, children are needed to carry on the civilization. You see absolutely no children in the entire episode which actually makes no sense. It seems the old men regard the festival as a regular event which they are now excused from due to the lack of their sexual abilities. It's about sex and children to carry on the civilization. As a robot under Landrus control there is no lust for sex, he had to periodically shut off his control so the sex starved population could continue.

Comment: it’s not working but he keeps doing it? So like a computer.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously the real reason for the festival was to have a little excitement in the show.
But of conjecture, (which apparently is something to avoid here,) I can see 2 reasons. The first being a way to free the pent up emotions from the subconscious. (Based on certain ideas of the mind.)
But with a computer running 24/7, it could be related to an annual computer maintenance where full control is not possible, and instead portions of the brain are temporarily shut down, leaving just a connection, and freeing up the resources for the task of maintenance.